# Meteor: error: Can't install npm dependencies

Tags: meteor, npm, freebsd, rocket.chat

I want to install Rocket.Chat and Meteor on Freebsd 10.3
Does anyone know why when running NPM through Meteor, it is failing to download and install the modules:

```
   [rocketchat@web ~/meteor]$ ./meteor -v
   meteor: updating npm dependencies -- meteor-deque...
    Building package meteor                   |
    /usr/home/rocketchat/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/ip-regex /index.js:3
    const word = '[a-fA-F\\d:]';
    ^^^^^
    babel-compiler: updating npm dependencies -- meteor-babel...
    ecmascript-runtime: updating npm dependencies -- meteor-ecmascript- runtime...
    promise: updating npm dependencies -- meteor-promise...
    npm-mongo: updating npm dependencies -- mongodb...
    logging: updating npm dependencies -- cli-color...
    xmlbuilder: updating npm dependencies -- xmlbuilder...
    Errors prevented isopacket build:

    While building package meteor:
    error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the    internet?

    While building package babel-compiler: 
    error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the   internet?

    While building package ecmascript-runtime:
    error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?
    error: File not found: .npm/package/node_modules/meteor-ecmascript- runtime/client.js

    While building package promise:
    error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?
    error: File not found: .npm/package/node_modules/meteor-promise /promise.bundle.js
```

Comment: `error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?` At the moment of installing were you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes! From which site is npm updated?

Comment: You're pulling from the npm registry https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry
Please, do try to reinstall things again. Start by your project if it doesn't work try to retinstall `Meteor CLI` and try again. 
Finally, you may want to check your network related configurations like /etc/hosts for example. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a working  installation procedure for Meteor on Freebsd 10.3?

Comment: No, mate. Although it's highly unlikely that Meteor wouldn't work on Freebsd 10.3, yet how about creating a docker image with Freebsd instead of Alpine and give it a go.